# How to optimize A-Frame html shader text to VR visualization?

Tags: three.js, aframe, html2canvas

Hello everyone so I've been trying to render a book page that is attached to your hand in VR (testing on oculus-go) using A-FRAME. Initially I tried using a plane and applying the text to it using the text attribute and then defining its value, alignment, font etc... Everything worked fine enough however the text gets "jagged edges" that seem to get worse the more you move your hand (which is basically impossible to not do) making it extremely bad for a long text-form such as a book page.

Then I tried exploring an alternative by using the aframe-html-shader by mayognaise. By creating an html div and using css it's the perfect solution in terms of customization, alignment and etc and when I render it, the text doesn't get any "jagged edges" anymore (since it's basically a texture).
However, it gets blurry enough that it becomes tiresome for long reads.

I've tried everything I could to increase its sharpness however it keeps being blurry which makes absolutely no sense to me.

What I've tried:

- Increasing the size of the object the texture applies to and then scaling it back after the render - result: same thing...
- Increasing the size of the canvas or the texture inside the aframe-html-shader.js - result: the same thing... however some of the tinkering attempts seem to trigger a  "image too big (...) scaling down to 4000" (4000 something I don't recall the exact value) which seem to indicate the canvas is already being rendered at full resolution
- Switching from Mayognaise aframe-html-shader.js to wildlifela fork (which already has an option of "scale" on the shader) and applying "canvasScale: 2" - result: same thing...
- Using a 4000px width html element as the object to render from, increasing the font accordingly- result: same thing...

I'm out of ideas and really don't understand why I can't get good enough text out of the html shader since if the text is within an image and I use that same image as a texture, the text comes out perfectly readable.

Need some help from all the A-Frame experts and developers over here!

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Increasing the size of the canvas or the texture inside the aframe-html-shader.js - result: the same thing... however some of the tinkering attempts seem to trigger a "image too big (...) scaling down to 4000" (4000 something I don't recall the exact value) which seem to indicate the canvas is already being rendered at full resolution

It wasn't too big. This is because textures needs to be a power of two size (e.g., 4096x4096).

The standard text component should be clearest though. A-Frame master branch has a fix to make text look clearer, might help. https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/commit/8d3f32b93633e82025b4061deb148059757a4a0f